# Oracle plsql catching exceptions

Tags: oracle, plsql

In a procedure I'm inserting values into different tables, whenever a unique/primary key violation occurs for a table, I want to handle the exception specifically for that table. How can I catch different duplicate value exceptions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check some tutorials like [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/when_others.php).

Your unique/primary key violation will be a `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception.

Comment: Hmm, but how will I know from which table insert it was thrown?

Comment: Then you probably have to wrap each of your statments with such an exception block or you set yourself a marker so that you know which has been the last successful insert.

Comment: Hmm, this will be for primary key violations, but can I handle foreign key errors differently?

Comment: This should throw an ORA-02291 check the last section. You can get the error code after doing a WHEN OTHERS. Make your behavior dependent on that error code.

Answer (score 0):

When you had created your table, you should have created a TRIGGER and a SEQUENCE to run Before Insert on your table and to catch if :NEW.PRIMAY_KEY is null then get it from the sequence.

Using this method you will always avoid DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX.

I would avoid using WHEN OTHERS as this has no real use in a real error handling logic.